# Multiple command executions from find

Tags: bash, find

Most people are familiar with using find to run the same command on a number of files, e.g.:

`find -type f | xargs command`

or

`find -type f -exec command {} \;`

My question is whether it's possible to run multiple commands from find:

`find [path] [expression] -exec command1 {} -exec command2 {} \;`

so that the output would look like

```
command1: file1
command2: file1
command1: file2
command2: file2
command1: file3
command2: file3
command1: file4
command2: file4
```

Obviously I can write a simple shell script wrapper for this, but is it possible to do it all from the command line (perhaps using `awk`, `tee` etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or

```
find . -exec echo {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like this.

```
find . -exec bash -c 'echo {} ; echo {} ' \;
```

Comment: Along with some "{}", this is perfect!

Comment: ... ok, I'll have to give it to the other one after all; it does actually give multiple -exec options. But this is also good.

Comment: This will break for commands other than echo if the filename contains spaces. This will even break for echo if a filename contains multiple consecutive spaces. The arguments passed to the command with {} are unquoted, and are thus separate arguments to the command. There is no way to properly quote the {}. To fix this, use the following syntax: `find . -exec bash -c 'echo "$1"; echo "$1" ' _ {} \;` where the _ will be $0 in bash, and {} will be $1, properly quoted. Or use JRT's solution above, which will properly pass arguments with spaces.